# Entering Passcode too quickly?

Tags: iphone, ios, password

Is there a setting or a way to have the phone accept the passcode more quickly?

**The Problem:**
My passcode is greater than 8 characters.  I've entered it enough times that I've become quite efficient at it.  The phone can't seem to keep up. After several attempts at ever decreasing speeds, I have to enter it at what seems 1 character per second.

To make sure that it's not me, we recorded me tapping in my passcode at a quick pace.  I tapped each number correctly.  Each tap highlighted the number and there was an audible "keyboard click".  The phone did not accept the correct passcode.  Entering the exact same passcode at a much slower rate, the phone accepted it.

Can this behavior from the phone be adjusted?

The phone is an iPhone 7S running IOS 13, not jailbroken.

Comment: Mix them together — jail broken

Comment: @mmmmmm - thanks for the terminology.

Comment: I don't believe there's any adjustments you can make for this.  I hate to say but your options might be to either reduce the number of characters or wipe the device and set it up again and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem. I don't see any way of adjusting or fixing this unfortunately. We just have to wait for Apple to fix this in a future release.